# How to cancel/reset workflow from Java Client?

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow, uber-cadence

I'm seeing cadence CLI supports the above commands from CLI interface.How to do this through Java SDK.I'm seeing support only for starting the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

#### Cancel

You can call this [RequestCancelWorkflowExecution](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.uber.cadence/cadence-client/3.6.1/com/uber/cadence/serviceclient/WorkflowServiceTChannel.html#RequestCancelWorkflowExecution-com.uber.cadence.RequestCancelWorkflowExecutionRequest-) API to cancel a workflow

#### Reset

You can call this [ResetWorkflowExecution API](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.uber.cadence/cadence-client/3.6.1/com/uber/cadence/serviceclient/WorkflowServiceTChannel.html#ResetWorkflowExecution-com.uber.cadence.ResetWorkflowExecutionRequest-) to reset a workflow

However, it only support resetting by a eventId as reset point. It doesn't allow resetting by resetTypes which are supported in the CLI, until [this issue](https://github.com/uber/cadence/issues/4289) is implemented.

For now, if you want to reset by resetTypes, you have to copy the logic from [this CLI implementation](https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/6ea8658c38c5c46967a0463a423d753db921effa/tools/cli/workflowCommands.go#L1738)